# Uploading photo to db using retrofit passing File type but it throws error no file path foung in log

Tags: java, android, api, file-upload, retrofit2

This is my api call in the fragment class where I deal with profile data, it displays the image on button click but doesn't upload the image to database.

```
public void uploadImage(File file){
        // Create a request body with File(file)
        RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), file);

        // Create a MultipartBody.Part from the request body
        MultipartBody.Part photo = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("photo", file.getName(), requestBody);
        Log.i("TAG", "uploadImage: file name " + file.getName());

        // Api call
        Call<ResponseBody> req = Client.getInstance(Consts.BASE_URL_PASSENGER_AUTH).getRoute().uploadProfilePhoto(photo, session.getToken(), session.getPassenger().getPassengerId());
        Log.i("TAG", "uploadImage: enqueueing " + photo + " " + session.getPassenger().getPassengerId());
        req.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
          @Override
          public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
              if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                  Log.i("TAG", "onResponse: image uploaded" );
                  Log.i("TAG", "onResponse: success file name " + photo);
              }
          }

         @Override
          public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
             Log.i("TAG", "onFailure: " + t.getLocalizedMessage());
         }
        });
    }
```

I have logged the onResponse and onFailure calls, and it goes to the onFailure call and says,

> 12006-12006 TAG                     com.example.sts_passenger            I  onFailure: /storage/emulated/0/Screenshot_20230523-073140_WhatsApp.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Api Handler, I am using in-built ResponseBody class for Call

```
@Multipart
    @POST(Consts.ENDPOINT_UPLOAD_PROFILE_PIC)
    Call<ResponseBody> uploadProfilePhoto(
            @Part MultipartBody.Part photo,
            @Header("Authorization") String userSessionToken,
            @Path("passenger_id") Integer passengerId);
```

Comment: Before upload use file.exists() and file.canRead().

Answer (score 0):

First Create a Utility Class as Below

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.OpenableColumns;
import android.text.format.Formatter;

import androidx.annotation.Keep;

// Created by Shahid Iqbal on 10/9/2022.

public class FileInfo {
    @Keep
    public static class FileDetail {
        private String fileName;
        private String fileType;
        private String fileExtension;
        private String fileSize;

        public FileDetail(String fileName, String fileType, String fileExtension, String fileSize) {
            this.fileName = fileName;
            this.fileType = fileType;
            this.fileExtension = fileExtension;
            this.fileSize = fileSize;
        }

        public String getFileName() {
            return fileName;
        }

        public String getFileType() {
            return fileType;
        }

        public String getFileExtension() {
            return fileExtension;
        }

        public String getFileSize() {
            return fileSize;
        }
    }

    public static FileDetail getFileInfo(Context context, Uri uri) {
        try (android.database.Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null)) {
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                int nameIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME);
                int sizeIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.SIZE);

                String fileName = cursor.getString(nameIndex);
                String fileType = context.getContentResolver().getType(uri).toString();
                String fileExtension = fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
                String fileSize = Formatter.formatFileSize(context, cursor.getLong(sizeIndex));

                return new FileDetail(fileName.substring(0, fileName.lastIndexOf(".")), fileType, fileExtension, fileSize);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

And then in your api call area do as following

```
 @SuppressLint("Recycle")
    private MultipartBody.Part createRequestBody(Uri uri, String name, Context context) {
        if (uri != null) {
            Uri.FileColumns fileInfo = uri.getFileInfo(context);
            String fileName = fileInfo.fileName + "." + fileInfo.fileExtension;
            File file = new File(context.getCacheDir(), fileName);

            try {
                OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                InputStream inputStream = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);

                if (inputStream != null) {
                    copyStream(inputStream, outputStream);
                    inputStream.close();
                }

                outputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse(fileInfo.fileType);
            RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(mediaType, file);
            return MultipartBody.Part.createFormData(name, file.getName(), requestBody);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    private void copyStream(InputStream input, OutputStream output) throws IOException {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4 * 1024];
        int bytesRead;
        while ((bytesRead = input.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
    }
}
```